# A loss of precision

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, precision

If I have a double string which is equal to `"123.546123"` and convert it to a double with `atof`, I get only `123.546`. What can I do to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::string a = "123.546123";
    double b = atof(a.c_str());

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You don't lose precision, it's just std::cout prints out double value by default at certain precision which is less then you expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::cout` prints floating-point values with a precision of 6 by default. To increase that precision, use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) from `<iomanip>`, e.g.:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << b << std::endl;
```